# Как в корзине задать для определенной категории товаров в инпуте шаг в 50 единиц, а также присвоить цену за эти 50 ед. чтобы был правильный расчет?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как в корзине товаров для определенной категории группы товаров (допустим у нас есть категория snack) присвоить шаг в инпуте в 50 единиц (50,100,150,200) и т.д? Допустим речь идёт о граммах.

Я пробовал использовать плагин WooCommerce Advanced Product Quantities, вроде бы получилось то что нужно, в плане шага в 50, но в плане расчета цены и в плане функциональности что-то он работал не совсем корректно. Может можно для категории snack задать правила или функцию для шага в инпуте, а также правила для корректного расчета??? Или есть ещё какие нибудь подходы или методы как можно решить такого рода вопрос. Фото прилагается, чтобы было наглядно понятно, что мне интересно узнать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Бррррррррррр...

Answer (score 1):

В functions.php надо добавить такой код:

```
function kagg_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if ($product->post->post_title == 'Кальмар') {
        $args['max_value']  = 200;  // Maximum value
        $args['min_value']  = 50;       // Minimum value
        $args['step']       = 50;    // Quantity steps
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'kagg_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
```

В примере проверяется, что товар называется "Кальмар". В этом случае устанавливается минимальное, максимальное количество и шаг изменения количества.

Работающий пример [здесь](http://test.kagg.eu/shop/).

Comment: Ваше решение мне помогло. Спасибо вам огромное! Дай бог вам здоровья!

Comment: Если ответ работает, его можно отметить, как принятый.